# Ionic Cordova: Is there a way to set fixed cordova-ios version

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Currently I am building an Ionic App.

When i clone a fresh copy of my repo and add platform ios, cordova-ios@5.0.1 is used because of following line in config.xml

```
<engine name="ios" spec="5.0.1" />
```

But when i remove platform iOS, this line also gets removed.

Therefore, on the next read cordova-ios@4.x.x gets installed. But I need at least version 5.0.1 otherwise the Google Maps plugin wont work.

Can i somehow force the use of cordova-ios@5.0.1?

Tried to find resolutions to the problems and tried various different settings in package.json and config.xml, nothing helps.

Comment: Have you checked following: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/incompatibility-to-cordova-ios-5-0-0/155877/50

Answer (score 1):

When adding the platform again (either in your build-script or manually), try

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@5.0.1
```

or

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@latest
```

Also the platform version is probably defined in your `package.json`. Maybe there the old version is set to 4.x.x, which is why it still downloads the older version, when not specifying the version yourself.

Comment: `ionic cordova platform add ios@5.0.1` 
Thats the way how i do it right now.
But if i remove the platform, the cordova-ios package also gets removed from package.json. So on next readd with `ionic cordova platform add ios` without @5, version 4 is automatically chosen.

Answer (score 0):

My solution right now:

I added 2 items to the scripts part in package.json

```
"add:ios": "ionic cordova platform add ios@5",
"rm:ios": "ionic cordova platform rm ios"
```

So the workaround now is to use

```
npm run add:ios
```

instead of

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@5
```